# wxPython + multiprocessing: Checking if a color string is legitimate

Tags: python, wxpython, multiprocessing

I have a wxPython program with two processes: A primary and a secondary one (I'm using the multiprocessing module.) The primary one runs the wxPython GUI, the secondary one does not. However, there is something I would like to do from the secondary process: Given a string that describes a color, to check whether this would be legitimate color for wxPython. That means, whether I can create a `wx.Pen(color_string)` or not.

How do I do this?

(I tried making a wx.Pen and comparing its color to the null color, but that required to create a wx.App in the second process, and when I did create one the program raised an error in some special wxPython window.)

Comment: Can you explain a bit more, what do you mean by valid color?
and why you need to create a Pen to check for color validity?
aren't all color in 255,255,255 range valid?

Comment: I'm talking about color as a string, which may be "red" or "black" or "#12322F", but not "blackk".

Answer (score 1):

You could make two Queues between the two processes and have the second one delegate wx-related functionality to the first one (by pushing on the first queue the parameters of the task to perform, and waiting for the result on the second one).

Comment: Yes, that had occurred to me... If there won't be anything simpler, that's what I'll have to do.